Cot-Caught Merger in NYC and New Jersey?
I'm a bit confused with the cot-caught and father-bother merger, especially as they appear in the NYC / New Jersey area? I'm a native of the area and have lived there my whole life, yet I have the merger and was very unfamiliar with the unmerged forms of the sounds (cot and caught both have the same sound as hot, taught, thought, stock, etc.). It seems like these places have very high concentrations of the sound (link).
Is it something that has just homogenized over time across the U.S., or is there another reason why the unmerged sounds might be less prevalent?

I'm also a native of the area, and my diction does not merge them.

It isn't necessarily regional, in my opinion.

NYC accents vary even within boroughs and obviously between classes, ages and ethnic groups. Like in any metro with more than ten million people.
